# Accessing Elements of sqlalchemy orm declarative base class

Tags: python, list, dictionary

I am trying to get list of 10 different zip codes closest to a lat/long combination using python's uszipcode(https://github.com/MacHu-GWU/uszipcode-project) . I cannot get the zipcodes in a list or a dictionary while using the code specified in documentation

```
>>> result = search.by_coordinates(39.122229, -77.133578, radius=30, returns=10)

search = SearchEngine(simple_zipcode=True)
result = search.by_coordinates(38.887563, -77.019929, radius=30,returns=10)
for zipcode in result:
nearestzip = zipcode.zipcode
 print(nearestzip) 
#output is list of 10 different zips 
nearestzip 
# output is last zipcode which is 20036 
nearestzip[0]
#output is 2
```

I am looking to retrieve/get all the 10 zipcodes in a list where i can access the first zipcode using nearestzip[0] , nearestzip[1]...

Comment: `nearestzip` is replaced every time in the loop and you end up with it having the last value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure exactly what you mean, but can you just loop over items in results?

```
nearestzip = [res.zipcode for res in result]
```